# juju can not reach servers

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I installed maas server and juju client tools, but when I try to run any deploy command or run `juju status` I get these error messages:

```
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.  Error details: no reachable servers.
Error: Unable to connect to environment "maas". Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.
Error details: no reachable servers
```

When I run `juju bootstrap` again I get this error:  `environment is already bootstrapped`

Answer (score 3):

1. After you have maas installed, you need to enlist and commission machines into maas, then can Juju ask maas for server for bootstrap and deploy.
2. You need get the credential by access maas's UI. That can be found in the MAAS Web UI under the user preferences.

Comment: Thanks for you answer , i allready i have 2 nodes are ready on maas server and when i run juju bootstrap one of them going to located to root user but i still got the error massage i mentioned before this my environment file, environments:
 maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://maas-server-ip-address/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: 'vzgAAtkW9YftwMRDxb:z9EHbEgsBjMNjbP5r4:9AdTb7gMU39FvPBKHsbPYNT9FAtFGscs'
    admin-secret: 'my-root-password'
    default-series: 'precise